# Can I add more than one behaviour in widgets in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Questions:

- Can I add more than one behaviour in widgets in Kivy?

Code:

```
<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior@HoverBehavior+Image>

<MyClass>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ImageButton:
            source: "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\NewGame.png"
            on_press:
                self.source = "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\NewGameClick.png"
            on_release:
                self.source = "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\NewGame.png"
```

Thanking You!!

Comment: The `ToggleButtonBehavior` extends `ButtonBehavior`, so there is no need to add both behaviors.

Comment: You only need the first `@`, after the first, use `+` only

Comment: @John I am making a HoverBehavior and I nned to add it with button behavior. How can I do this? Like this?`<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+HoverBehavior+Image>`

Comment: Like the above comment? @Eric

Comment: It worked!!! @John Anderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Erik's comment like this!

```
<ImageButton@ButtonBehaviour+HoverBehavior+Image>

<MyClass>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ImageButton:
            source: "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\NewGame.png"
            on_press:
                self.source = "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\NewGameClick.png"
            on_release:
                self.source = "C:\\Users\\kanna\\Pictures\\OpenCity-Main_Menu\\PNG\\NewGame.png"
```

Remove the second `@` and replace with `+`!